# get details on file then insert to database

Tags: php, database, file, csv, readfile

I have a **.txt** file with details of all countries in this format:

```
Country,City,AccentCity,Region,Population,Latitude,Longitude
ad,aixas,Aixàs,06,,42.4833333,1.4666667
ad,aixirivali,Aixirivali,06,,42.4666667,1.5
ad,aixirivall,Aixirivall,06,,42.4666667,1.5
ad,aixirvall,Aixirvall,06,,42.4666667,1.5
ad,aixovall,Aixovall,06,,42.4666667,1.4833333
ad,andorra,Andorra,07,,42.5,1.5166667
ad,andorra la vella,Andorra la Vella,07,20430,42.5,1.5166667
ad,andorra-vieille,Andorra-Vieille,07,,42.5,1.5166667
ad,andorre,Andorre,07,,42.5,1.5166667
ad,andorre-la-vieille,Andorre-la-Vieille,07,,42.5,1.5166667
ad,andorre-vieille,Andorre-Vieille,07,,42.5,1.5166667
ad,ansalonga,Ansalonga,04,,42.5666667,1.5166667
```

I've to insert these data into 3 tables like cities, states and country with out duplication.

Any possible way to read the datas from the .txt file and insert it to the database?

How can I get the state and city database?

Comment: You just have to read the file, split each line bei commata, create your INSERT statement ... done(?)

Answer (score 2):

Read the file as a CSV and then insert:

```
if (($handle = fopen("cities.txt", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
        // Craft your SQL insert statement such as:
        $sql = "INSERT INTO cities (country, city, accent_city, etc.) VALUES ('{$data[0]}','{$data[1]}','{$data[2]}', etc.)";
        // Use the appropriate backend functions depending on your DB, mysql, postgres, etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to insert into 3 seperate tables like country state city

Comment: Sure, just keep in mind that your data set is for cities and so you'll have duplicate countries if you just insert the first column every time. Edit your question to include your table definitions and I can update the answer to show you how you might do it.

Comment: I need only the states and cities of philippines ie $data[0]=ph

Answer (score 0):

If you database is mysql, exists an utility to bulk insert, [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

If not, probably your database has one too, but if you want to do this using PHP, @davidethell's example is good for do the task